# how to obtain a splash screen to display a message?

Tags: java, splash-screen

How can i obtain a  *flash message* ( *a black screen that splashes for few seconds*) on screen for the time limit that i suggest ?

The whole screen of the computer should go black and there should be a message at the center.

For example in the following picture the length and width will be the length and width of the screen of the monitor:

[image]

*Message covering the whole screen*

I want this to be fired if a button is click or on it's own when some event is fired.

Comment: a bit more information is required here @Suhail if you want a meaningful answer

Comment: @ griegs what information ? I want that when i click on a button a message of the form displayed above should come up and should cover the whole screen. _black background and some other color for the text_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class displayFullScreen extends JFrame { 
        private JLabel alarmMessage = new JLabel("Alarm !");
        private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        public displayFullScreen() {
            setUndecorated(true);
            panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
            alarmMessage.setText("Alarm !");
            alarmMessage.setFont(new Font("Cambria",Font.BOLD,100));
            alarmMessage.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
            panel.add(alarmMessage);
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height);
            panel.setBackground(Color.black);
            add(panel);

            addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
               public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
                   escapeHandler(ke);
               } 
            });
        }

        public void escapeHandler(KeyEvent ke) {
            if(ke.getKeyCode() == ke.VK_ESCAPE) {
                displayFullScreen.this.dispose();
            } 
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean. Try this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html). [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/SplashDemoProject/src/misc/SplashDemo.java)  is also an example provided by Oracle for splash screens.

Next time, be sure to provide more information.

Comment: Though he used the term *splash screen* i'm not sure if he need this, he need to trigger that every time he clicks a button.

Comment: what information ? I want that when i click on a button a message of the form displayed above should come up and should cover the whole screen._black background and some other color for the text_

Answer (score 0):

> Here are my suggestions,
>   Since you want this every time you click a button, the splash screen is not a viable solution.I think you have to make a window with your message,but keep in mind that going full screen isn't as simple as making a large panel, you need to look into the underlying OS graphics. Here is a solution [to create a full-screen (non-windowed) application in Java](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=53106) which might be helpful to you.

Also I suggest you to have a look at the [Java's Full-Screen mode API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html) .